# vb.net using ashx handler to get image from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, ashx

I have employee images stored in my `EMPPhotos` table on SQL Server 2008 R2 in an `image` datatype. I created a generic handler to get the image from the table and send it to the page. It does not work. I have tested the query itself and I am getting data.

The handler:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="EmpImageHandler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class EmpImageHandler : Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        'context.Response.ContentType = "text/bmp"
        'context.Response.Write("Hello World")

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/bmp"
        Dim img As Image = GetImage(context.Request.QueryString("id"))
        img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Bmp)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetImage(inID As Long) As Image
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream

        Dim cnSTR As New clsConnections
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection(cnSTR.ConnectToDB("AgencyStaff"))
        Try
            cn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Dim ssql As String = "Select BMPPhoto From EMPPhotos where empid = " & inID
        Dim CMD As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(ssql, cn)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = CMD.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        Dim img() As Byte = CType(dr("BMPPhoto"), Byte())
        ms = New MemoryStream(img, False)
        Return Image.FromStream(ms)
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Change your `ContentType`.

From:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/bmp"
```

To:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp"
```