# Retrieving an image saved in a SQL Server table as a <Binary Data> using the id of the user

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, image

I have a SQL Server table with an `image` column. I have stored the image as  binary data and I would like to retrieve this image and present it in an `Image` control using an `ImageUrl`.

Generic handler code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select admin_image from admin where Id=" +context.Request.QueryString["imageid"]+"", con);

SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])myReader["admin_image"]);
}
```

Calling the generic handler on page-load

```
image.ImageUrl = "Handler1.ashx?imageid=" + Request.Cookies["login"]["login_id"]; //id of the user in SQL table from which we want to retrieve the image
```

The code gets compiled without problems but I just seem not to get the image loaded. The `id` I am sending is the correct one.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: You really really need to use parameters. if someone visited `Handler1.ashx?imageid='';Drop table admin;` it would take down your site. See [a tutorial here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06), you should never ever ever use `" + someData +"` in a query.

Comment: Except for VB vs C#, quite possible a duplicate of [using ashx handler to get image from SQL Server]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536690/vb-net-using-ashx-handler-to-get-image-from-sql-server