# vb.net - include .js file from local system on ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scriptmanager

I have a scriptmanager which I am accessing through vb.net code. I would like to have it include a .js script that is on the server's local filesystem and is not being hosted on the server. It is possible to include images which are not being hosted (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=netframework-4.7.2) and are on the local filesystem. Is it possible to do this somehow for a .js file?

I am looking for something such as RegisterClientScriptInclude, but which allows me to use .js files from the local filesystem.

Comment: Well you can grab images and files from the controller because all of that code is run server-side.  But are you trying to use that javascript code on the HTML/Razer/aspx/whatever page?  You could serve up any file you wanted as a FileResult return type if not.  Also, you could convert it to a string and drop the javascript file contents somewhere on the page inside <script> tags.

Comment: I dont think that is possible. But you can always go around and do just that by using http handler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536690/vb-net-using-ashx-handler-to-get-image-from-sql-server